# Print Original String in Java

Tags: java

So my program determines whether the user input is a palindrome or not. However, if the input contains a mixture of upper and lower case then the final output would all be lower case. How do I make it so that it outputs the original user input.

Current: User input = Aa. Output = aa is a palindrome.

Objective: User input = Aa. Output = Aa is a palindrome.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Colonies { 
    static char [] string;
    static int length; 
    private static Scanner scan;

    public static void main (String[] args){ 

        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string of characters."); 

        String s = scan.nextLine(); 
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        string = s.toCharArray();
        length = string.length; 
        if (isPalindrome()){ 
            System.out.println(s+" is a palindrome."); 
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println(s+" is not a palindrome."); 
        } 
    } 

    public static boolean isPalindrome(){
        boolean palindrome = true; 

        for (int c = 0; c < length/2; c++){ 
            if(string[c] != string [length - c - 1]){ 
                palindrome = false; 
            } 
        } 

        if (palindrome){ 
            return true; 
        } else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it return the original string, just save a copy of the original string. and if the copy is palindrome, just return the original string, not the copied one.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `toLowerCase` on the input string.  Instead, defer your case conversion to the point where you do the comparison, i.e. change

```
if(string[c] != string [length - c - 1]){
```

to

```
if(Character.toLowerCase(string[c]) != Character.toLowerCase(string [length - c - 1])){
```

That way you will still get the comparison you want without having to modify the input.

Answer (score 0):

`s = s.toLowerCase();` This code is changing your `Aa` to `aa`